# All invariant subspaces of a projection

Tags: linear-algebra

I want to show that the only invariant subspaces of a rank 2 projection $P:\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^3$ either contain $\ker P$ or are contained on Im $P$, but I'm having some trouble arguing this: for starters, $P$ has only eigenvalues $0$ and $1$, so the correspondent eigenspaces $W_0$ and $W_1$ and it is clear that these satisfy the desired property. Conversely, I could take an arbitrary $P$-invariant subspace $W$ and consider each case by it's dimension, but I wonder if there isn't another argument I'm missing here. Maybe that would help to see why it is necessary to have rank $2$ here as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the assumptions $\dim \ker P=1$ and $\dim im P =2$.

Let $W$ be an invariant subspace. Assume $\ker P \not \subset W$. Then there is $x\in \ker P \setminus W$. Hence $x\ne0$, and $\ker P \cap W = \{0\}$ by $\dim\ker P=1$.
Now let $w\in W$. Then $w = (I-P)w + Pw$. We have $(I-P)w\in \ker P$ by $P^2=P$. But also $(I-P)w\in W$ by $P$-invariance of $W$. Hence $(I-P)w=0$ and $w=Pw$, so $W \subset im P$.

This proves: $\ker P \subset W$ or $W\subset im P$.

Now assume $\ker P \subset im P$. Then $Px=P(Px)=0$ for all $x$, hence $P=0$, which is excluded by the rank condition.